# 404 error but the files/directory is there

Tags: c#, migration, iis-8

I know this has been asked,t I have scoured everywhere that I can try to read on this, but nothing seems to help so I would appreciate some feedback!

I am in the process of migrating an application from a windows 2003 to a windows 2012 R2 server. The application is old, but it has been converted to version 2.0.5 and should run on CLRV2.0. In IIS, I have it set to classic as well, aspx is enabled in the handler mappings as well. This is the only application doing this of the ones migrated and they are all from the same server/time period.

The binding are set up properly and the file is definitely in the folder.

Has anyone run into this issue or know of a way to fix this? The Server also should already have everything needed installed in roles/features.

Comment: Check permissions on what ID/user (system or otherwise) is executing the app and confirm it has permissions to the file/folder.  Also verify that where the app is running from has access to even see the directory from the server it is running on and check the path to ensure it is correct (using a named drive path vs. full network path can help as well)

Comment: Ensure you're downloading a file that has a registered mine type, or register a new type